# How to change path for saving xml file

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am new in asp.net mvc.

i am saving xml file using:

```
string appPath = Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\" + "test.xml";

System.IO.File.WriteAllText(xml, appPath);
```

but its save on this directory

```
"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IIS Express\\test.xml"
```

we want to save in project directory root folder pls give me solution.

Regards,
Jatin

Comment: Um, just don't use `Environment.CurrentDirectory`. I'm not sure what you mean by "my project directory root folder" but you might want to look at `HostingEnvironment.MapPath` or `Server.MapPath`.

Comment: This is asp.net or windows form application?

Comment: @HassanNisar no,its a asp.net mvc web application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

`Server.MapPath("~");`

Or

```
HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath
```

to get root folder of your application.

Also, switch the parameters of `File.WriteAllText` (since the first one is the file path) :-

```
File.WriteAllText(appPath, xml)
```